# GET hanging on redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I can see POST go and complete in firebug console, and I see the GET start, but hangs and never ends. Anyone experience this and/or know what might be causing it?

Routes:

```
Route::post('recipes/submitList', array('uses'=>'recipes@submitList'));
Route::get('results/list', array('as'=>'list', 'uses'=>'recipes@list'));
```

Controlller:

```
class Recipes extends Base_Controller{
    public function post_submitList(){
            // builds array from DB
            // etc
    return Redirect::to_route('list')
        ->with('list', $ingrs);
}
public function get_list(){
    return View::make('list')
        ->with('title', 'Your Shopping List!');
    }
}
```

In addition, if I echo the response out via console.log(response), I get all the HTML from the page I want to be redirected to. However, the GET that is cycling in the console has no response, but does have a "200 OK [cycle-gif] 313ms".

Comment: Do you have a `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the bootstrapper?

Comment: Try running fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and ensure the GET isn't stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks for the fiddler tip... I don't know what I'm looking at, but a screen of some weird characters in raw header here: http://i.imgur.com/22iE2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In your Get http verb, your are using 'results/list', and maybe it should be 'recipes/list'.

```
Route::get('recipes/list', array('as'=>'list', 'uses'=>'recipes@list'));
```

Comment: I can def try it and let you know. The first part is the query (or uri), as is a hard name, and uses tells it which controller@method. Stay tuned...